# How do I store navigation in aurelia store?

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-store

How can I store navigation and clicks (the router state changes) with aurelia store? Why doesn't it do this out of the box?

Comment: Well, it's hard to answer your Q. I don't think aurelia store should make the assumption that all apps will use the router. For that reason, I think it shouldn't try to store anything by default. For your Q, maybe you can use the router events here to hook into the router to do your own stuff?